# how to improve the performance of the hazelcast queue?

Tags: hazelcast

all

I met a problem :

`i can put 3000 messages into a queue per second on the one-node-hazelcast queue; but can only put 300 message into a queue perseconde on the two-node-hazelcast queue.`

how can i improve it?

is there any other solution to improve it?

is rabbitMq faster then hazelcat?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing 300 ops/second is very low. Even 3000 items/second on a queue on a single node cluster is very low. One should easily be doing 100k+ for local setup. On a 4 node cluster on 4 stale dual socket sandy bridge boxes with a crappy 1 GbE one should be able to do in the hundreds of thousands of operations/second.

What are you putting on that queue? Can you explain the content of the items and which serialization technology is used (e.g. Java Serializable). To make sure it isn't your serialization, try putting a Long on the queue and see what kind of performance you get.

A few other questions are

- what kind of hardware are you using
- do you have any special map configuration?

Comment: ps: hazelcast likes threads. So if you add more threads and more queues, your performance is likely to increase.